# rsync to copy only particular folders

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a dir with files and dirs in it. What I want is to make rsync copy of several folders from that dir. For example, lets say I have this:

```
/home/user
-- drwxr-xr-x  folderA
-- drwxr-xr-x  folderB
-- drwxr-xr-x  folderC
-- -rw-r--r--  file.1
-- -rw-r--r--  file.2
```

I want to copy folderA and folerB using rsync. I have created file rsync_folders.txt

```
+ /folderA/**
+ /folderB/**
```

My problem is that rsync will always copy file unless it matches exclude pattern. But if I add

```
- /**
```

nothing is copied because rsync first matches against exclude patterns.

Any ideas?

Note: I cannot list all folders and files I want to exclude. It will be changing from time to time.

Comment: What's the problem with rsync --recursive folderA folderB folderC destination ?

Comment: note that in recent versions of rsync /*** does what you want...

Comment: note, that indeed the _order_ of the include vs. exclude[-files] parameters matter! — Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either use `rsync -av src1 src2 src3 ... dst` or put all the folders you want to rsync in a text file (each folder in a separate line) and use `rsync -arv --files-from=sources.txt dst`.
Note that by default `-a` implies `--recursive` but not when `--files-from` is used, so in this case `-r` must be specified explicitly.

Comment: Putting all folders in test file does not work for me cuz I am using several exclude and include rules already. rsync src1 src2 src3 works for me.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4052/georgy-bolyuba ... I wrote a script.  Simplifying greatly I made one function to do the `rsync` command itself and passed: `scr` and `dst` folders which I call when the script  "argument"(s) met the requisite  _rules_.